# Coefficients of taylor series of an analytic function about different centers.

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, analytic-functions

To be concrete, I would like to limit my question to the exponential function and real numbers. The power series centered at any point converges to the exponential because its radius of convergence is infinite. Yet, when calculating the Taylor series about two different centers (say 0 and 1) the coefficients of the Taylor series are not the same. How is it possible then that both series expansions converge to the same exponential? Shouldn't the coefficients be the same?
Is it possible to operate with the expansions about the two centers and prove that they are actually the same polynomial, namely that the coefficients after reordering do are the same?

Comment: Why should the coefficients be the same? One is $\sum_n a_nx^n$, one is $\sum_n b_n(x-1)^n$

Comment: Yes, but both series are equal to e^x. Roughly speaking one has: "polynomial with infinite terms" = exponential function. If the coefficients are not the same that would mean that there are infinitely many polynomials that converge to the exponential, one for every different center. Is that the case?

Comment: I think you are asking a confusing question. Are you saying that you want to expand all $(x-1)^n$ and group the coefficients in terms of powers of $x$? Then you will get the same series. But $a_0=\sum_n b_n$, $a_1=\sum_n nb_n$ and so on. So you can write the coefficients of one representation as an infinite sum of coefficients from the other representation

Comment: Exactly, by reordering I meant expanding all the (x-1)^n and grouping the coefficients in terms of power of x. Is there a proof for the coefficients after expansion and grouping being the same?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JL0p7HCig6Q

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess I was confused by the notion of doing the taylor series about different centers of an analytic function such as the exponential. I guess then in the case of an analytic function it doesn't make so much sense to talk about series expansions about different centers because the series is always the same, just written in a different form (other than when we are only approximating with some terms).

Comment: The Taylor series for a function $f$ at a point $a$ is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!} (x-a)^k$. Thus the coefficients vary with the point you are expanding about. If $a,b$ are distinct points, then the truncated sums $p_{n,a} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$ are polynomials which satisfy different properties, being approximations to $f$ at the points $a$ and $b$, are different.

Answer (score -1):

@Abraham It might be more instructive if you say: How does the expansion of e^z at zero differ from that of e^z at 1? What you are overlooking is that when you expand (z -  1)^3 (only a few terms), you should, comapare,for example,the first few coefficients of z^3 and
(z-1)^3. Things look very different, don't they? That is so, because you must expand (z-1)^3! and then gather terms before starting to build the coefficients....

The expansion of (z-1)^3,does get more than a little "messy". Consider what (z-1)^112 looks like! It'll expand to 113 terms, Namely,
a0 + a1*z + a2*z^2 + ...........................+a112*z^112.
Do you want to compute those coefficients that are that expansion at 1. The same observations that are made here are true for real analytic functions, as well.

Sorry for so much text. I do not know any LaTex!